# Not able to write down the methods for addStudent and removeStudent for an arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist, constructor

I have created my array list to hold student details.

```
private ArrayList<Student> classList;
```

Then I initialized it in the constructor.

```
Course(String courseName)
{
 this.courseName = input.next();
 this.classList = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

I need to write down two methods which will addStudents and removeStudents into the arrayList. I am finding it difficult to do it. Any help or tip on how to deal with this?

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Consider looking at the methods provided by the `List<>` and `ArrayList<>` classes. You can find them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: I am not able to populate the arrayList with students in my addStudents method . I have not done it before .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList already has the methods to add and remove.

Student theStudent;

To add a student:

```
classList.add(theStudent);
```

To remove a student:

```
classList.remove(theStudent);
```

Comment: If you need to (like as a requirement) you can just put these calls into your own methods.

Comment: I tried this but I get an error that arguments is not applicable for (String) .

Comment: public void addStudent(Student student)
 {
  classList.add("theStudent");
 }

This is how my method looks like . I have a type Student .

Comment: The student that you passed should be the parameter for adding or removing.

Comment: I am trying to create a method to find the Max marks in a class . 
 My code looks like :  

 public double calculateMax()
    {
       double max = classList(0); 

       for ( double i = 0; i <= classList.length - 1; i++ )
       {
          if ( classList[i] > max )
             max = classList[i]; 
       }
       return max;

    }

I am not able to point to the first element of my arrayList . Also there are other error which the compiler shows up like the length is not a field . Any suggestions to overcome these errors ? What do u think about this ?

Comment: Start by observing the [ArrayList class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29). The length isn't a field, you want to use classList.size() to get the number of elements in the list.